# How to translate inline entity form nodes (or, product variations in kickstart)

Tags: commerce, i18n-l10n

My parent nodes need to be translatable - so i'm slated to use the out-of-the box internationalization module for that. However, one of the fields in this content type is an inline entity field which references another content type. Both the parent and the referenced nodes need to be translatable.

Now, is this a job for entity translate? I've tried with no success - but perhaps i'm not using the right combination. Presently if I set both the parent and child nodes to entity translate types I get an ajax error when I try to add the first child node (regardless of which fields are setup).

Comment: Do you mean you need a way to translate the referenced entity through the inline entity field? You should be able to translate entities with entity translate. So when does the error occur?

Comment: You should look into the inline entity form issue queue. I think to remember they had an issue about entity translation.

Comment: Error occurs when I click "add node" - thats when I get the ajax error. Donquixote - i've looked around with nearly zero luck. Some folks have attempted to tackle this with entity translate - but at best all the patches seem to do is set the language for the referenced child node. And when you view the node in a a translated language - it still uses the original.

Comment: I realize stopshinal found this issue already, but for everyone else: https://drupal.org/node/1545896.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure on the setup, but I just finished a site that dealt with a similar circumstance. It uses [String Overrides](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) to perform targeted text changes, and if it doesn't support Internationalization by default then there's a module that provides additional tabs at `/admin/config/regional/stringoverrides` for each enabled language.

For reference, here's the translation module list currently enabled on the site:

```
Locale
String Overrides
Entity Translation
Entity Translation Upgrade
Block languages
Contact translation
Field translation 
Internationalization
Menu Translation
Multilingual content
Rules Translation
Synchronize Translations
Translation Sets
Views Translation
Variable
```

Not all of these modules are required to make this happen, but perhaps you can compare your own setup to this list and find some differences. Apologies for not remembering how to set this up.

**UPDATE ::** *Process for enabling translation within String Overrides*

== Modules ==

- Internationalization :: [link](https://drupal.org/project/i18n) | [download](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/i18n-7.x-1.10.tar.gz)
- String Overrides :: [link](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) | [download](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/stringoverrides-7.x-1.8.tar.gz)
- Variable :: [link](https://drupal.org/project/variable) | [download](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/variable-7.x-2.4.tar.gz)

  1. Enable Modules:

     - Locale
     - Variable
     - Internationalization
     - String Overrides
     - String Translation
  2. Add a new language

     - /admin/config/regional/language/add
     - Select, click "Add language"
  3. Add translations for alt language strings

     - /admin/config/regional/stringoverrides, click desired language in top right
     - Add rows for each desired string, place original language text in left box and translated string in right box
     - Save, view on front end

The final interface should look something like the following cap: [image: string overrides with translation interface]

Comment: Could you elaborate on your solution, npc? I'm intrigued because it may be the only viable solution!

Comment: Updated with instructions.